# Fabric js fit object to left and right center of canvas

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Here i am trying to set object on center of the canvas.Fit center command is working good.Having issue with fit to left center command.
see the bellow snapshot for fit center command.when i scale the text in larger size and set it center its working good.

Demo Link:-  [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/759FV/93/)

[image: Fit to center]

But when i scale same object and run the command Fit To left center you can see here object is going outside of the center origon y of the grid.

[image: Fit to left center]

And when i set default text (without scale) and run the command Fit To left center its working good like bellow snap shot.

[image: Fit to left center without scale]

**Bellow is my sample code to fit object in center left of canvas**

```
$("#fitleft").click(function() {
            $("#fitleft").css('display','none');
   $("#fitright").css('display','block');   

   var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();



    obj.set( {
              left: 315.4000015258789,
             // top: Top
             top: obj.get('top')  
               });        

            obj.setCoords();
                      canvas.renderAll();



   });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made the answer for this

Demo Link:- [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/759FV/95/)

```
document.getElementById('fticenter').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
     obj.center();

     obj.setCoords();


     canvas.renderAll();


});

document.getElementById('fittoleftcenter').addEventListener('click', function (e) {




    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();

           var leftcenter=    canvas.width/2
        var halfleft = obj.currentWidth /2; 


       obj.set("left", leftcenter - halfleft);
       obj.set("top", obj.get('top'));   

            obj.setCoords();
                      canvas.renderAll();



   });


document.getElementById('fittorightcenter').addEventListener('click', function (e) {




    var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    var rightcenter=    canvas.width/2
        var halfright = obj.currentWidth /2; 
      obj.set("left", rightcenter - halfright);
       obj.set("top", obj.get('top'));    

            obj.setCoords();
                      canvas.renderAll();



   });
```